# calling cms static block on product detail page

Tags: product, product-view

I want to call my cms static block on product detail page above price ,

I have added  the below code via admin category > custom design .

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block_here"}}
```

Can anyone help me ,Where i goes to wrong.

Comment: what you have try can you please let me know in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:** You `cannot` set product details page layout from Category  `>custom design` tab.

For show a `static block at product detail and want to set this cms block from admin` .Then you need to goto  `admin>Catalog>Manage Product >` select any product  and Goto if it design tab and put this code

```
<reference name="product.info">
<block type="cms/block" name="mystaticblock" >
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>YOUR_BLOCK_ID</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

As product detail page main layout template is view.phtml, and it `doesn't render it child block automatically`, so on catalog/product/view.phtml add those code  block by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mystaticblock')?>` for render te block.

**Note: from admin manage you can only set cms  block for one page.**

Comment: i do not want to do any code changes can i do in some layout update to make it work

Comment: want for all proudcts of specific product

Comment: yeah .........................

Comment: want for all proudcts or  specific product