# add phtml page block before additional block on product detail page

Tags: product, product-view

i want add phtml page block before additional block on product detail page

i want to do it vai catalog > catagory > custom design update (apply to products) i am able to add some custom block which show content from some file like path/abc.phtml

i am able to override block using code like below there

```
<reference name="product.info.media">
      <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>smartwave/zoom/product/view/media_bundled.phtml</template>
      </action>
</reference>
```

can u guide me xml code needed to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** You `cannot` set product details page layout from Category  `>custom design` tab.

For show a `static block at product detail and want to set this cms block from admin` .Then you need to goto  `admin>Catalog>Manage Product >` select any product  and Goto if it design tab and put this code

```
<reference name="product.info">
<block type="cms/block" name="mystaticblock" >
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>YOUR_BLOCK_ID</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

As product detail page main layout template is view.phtml, and it `doesn't render it child block automatically`, so on catalog/product/view.phtml add those code  block by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mystaticblock')?>` for render te block.

**Note: from admin manage you can only set cms  block for one page.**

[Answer Link:](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62302/calling-cms-static-block-on-product-detail-page)

Answer (score 1):

If you want create custom block on product detail page, then following can be helpful.

Add layout in your custom module.

> /app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Add following lines in **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
     <block class="Custom\Module\Block\Product\Sizechart" name="size.chart" after="-" template="sizechart.phtml" />
   </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Then create block in Block folder like,

> /app/code/Custom/Module/Block/Product/Sizechart.php

Add following in Sizechart.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Product;
class Sizechart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ){
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

Then create phtml file in view/templates path like,

> /app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/templates/sizechart.phtml

Add your custom code there,

```
.......
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
.......
```